# Returning warnings from custom msbuild in TFS

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2018, I have a build step which calls on a batch script which sets various environment variables and involves msbuild on a solution file. Currently, if a project has warnings, there's no way to view them in TFS unless you look at the log files and see what the warnings are. If you run a native Visual Studio Build task, warnings are shown to you after a build.

How can I return warnings to TFS after my msbuild command completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to return warnings and errors from your script using [logging commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

e.g.:

For PowerShell script you can use below logging commands:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Test warning"
Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Test error"
```

For Batch script:

```
@echo ##vso[task.logissue type=warning;]Test warning
@echo ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]Test error
```

Reference this thread : [Is it possible to raise and display build warnings from build steps using TFS 2015?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573)

Comment: So if I produce 2 warning message, the build summary that is generated in the build result emails will display 2 warnings occurred during the build?

Comment: @shaboinkin Yes, you can check [mattbrooks2010's comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/573#issuecomment-142654821) in the linked thread in above answer.